# How to set angularjs input value using selenium(python)

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

In the target webpage, there is an angularjs input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" placeholder="Role name" ng-model="selectedRole.roleName" maxlength="50">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RcFa.jpg)
And i can locate the element using selenium(python) by using `(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[ng-model="selectedRole.roleName"]')`, but cannot set its value, can anybody help on this, thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you set its value? show us your code

Comment: The method I tried:   role_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[ng-model="selectedRole.roleName"]')   1. role_name.send_keys("alvin")   2. self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value","alvin");',role_name), both are not working. BTW, I can get the element value by using role_name.get_attribute("value")

Comment: @Alvin Did you tried before set value to wait until element visible using `WebDriverWait`..??

Answer (score 1):

Once you've located the `input` element, just *send the keys* to it:

```
role_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[ng-model="selectedRole.roleName"]')
role_name.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: I tried the method before, and got below error:Message: element not visible (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64), And i also tried to use execute_script:             self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value","alvin");',roleInput), still no lucky

Comment: @Alvin I wonder if this input is intentionally hidden, or is this just a timing issue?

Comment: I add an image link for the input. is it because the input control implemented by angularjs style?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait before send_keys using `WebDriverWait` until element to be visible as below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
role_name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[ng-model="selectedRole.roleName"]')))

#now go for set value
role_name.send_keys("alvin")
```

If you are still unable to set value try using `execute_script` as below :

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'alvin'", role_name)
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Thank you, @Saurabh! I tried your method, still no lucky, I am wondering if selenium fully support angularjs applications?

Comment: What do you mean still no lucky?? Is there any exception?? Please share it

Comment: I got a "TimeoutException" error with blank message

Comment: did you look for frame or iframe??? Make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access and set value using the below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-model = 'selectedRole.roleName']")
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@ng-model = 'selectedRole.roleName']"))).send_keys('Your Value')
```